# conda environment variable cannot be reached in python code

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I see few similar questions like this on stackoverflow, but none of them is resolved (or maybe i missed the trial), anyways, I would like to raise this question again see if anyone can help with it:

I have set the conda environment variable as below:

> conda env config vars set variable1=<variable1_value>

And when I list down the variable in conda environment, I can see it is successfully set:

> conda env config vars list

But when I try to fetch this same variable in python code, it is returning None. Python code is configured running with above same conda environment:

> 

```
os.getenv("variable1")
```

Does anyone has a clue why is it?

Comment: Did you reactivate the environment after setting the env variables?

Comment: @nigh_anxiety, yes, deactivate and reactivated